# Join JavaPairRDD and JavaPairDStream in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, left-join, spark-streaming

I have **JavaPairDStream>String, Long> stream** and  **JavaPairRDD >String, Long> batch**.
Now I want to join these two. Basically I want to join real time data with Batch data using Spark. But directly using JavaPairDStream inside argument to join is giving error. What changes I have to make to join these two. Also is this right way or there is another method to combine batch view and real time view in spark.

For example: `stream.leftOuterJoin(batch);`
This shows error. I know they are two different data types but since JavaPairDStream is abstraction for real time RDD it should work.

Any suggestions regardinf how I can join batch view and real time view would be helpful. Thanks.

And sorry for the wrong **>** in JavaPairDStream and  JavaPairRDD. I wasn't able to find correct escape character to write it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have got the solution as mentioned here [Transform Operation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers)

**Transform Operation**

The transform operation (along with its variations like transformWith) allows arbitrary RDD-to-RDD functions to be applied on a DStream. It can be used to apply any RDD operation that is not exposed in the DStream API. For example, the functionality of joining every batch in a data stream with another dataset is not directly exposed in the DStream API. However, you can easily use transform to do this. This enables very powerful possibilities. For example, if you want to do real-time data cleaning by joining the input data stream with precomputed spam information (maybe generated with Spark as well) and then filtering based on it.

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
// RDD containing spam information
final JavaPairRDD<String, Double> spamInfoRDD = jssc.sparkContext().newAPIHadoopRDD(...);
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> cleanedDStream = wordCounts.transform( new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>, JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>>() {
          @Override public JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> call(JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> rdd) throws Exception {

      rdd.join(spamInfoRDD).filter(...); 
      // join data stream with spam information to do data cleaning
  ...
    }
});
```